# NGINX stuck in HTTPS redirection on server

Tags: nginx

I've been trying to set up a self-signed certificate on my server (for when you visit the IP, not some domain, since I don't have any domains linked). I followed certain tutorials and made one using openssl and put my files here.
`/etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt`

I then created a configuration snippet in /etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf, which looks like this.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
```

After that, I just created an ssl-params.conf which contains the following:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# Disable strict transport security for now. You can uncomment the following
# line if you understand the implications.
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

And lastly, since I have no server blocks, I put the configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
Which is a simple one that I took.

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration

   listen 443 ssl default_server;
   listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

   include snippets/self-signed.conf;
   include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
   return 302 https://$host$request_uri;

location ~ / {
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}
```

But now whenever I visit the IP of the server, it gives me the problem of it being redirected too many times. I can't seem to find what I did wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {listen 443 ssl;

    server_name  localhost;


    ssl_certificate     D:/yourcertificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key D:/yourcertificate.key;




    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

  location / {
   # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
   proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
}}
```

Follow this link https://youtu.be/ikbN1bYnBjg for better understanding.

Comment: I've put the same, it now connects but it gives me a bad gateway issue.

Comment: Does your localhost:8080?

Comment: Does your localhost:8080 or application server works fine?

Comment: I don't run any application that needs a redirect to port 8080, I simply want to serve the files on port 80 normally.

Comment: Which files your are going to host on port 80.

Comment: Static files that are on /var/www/html/